# Redirecting and performing click event on other page with href using ASP .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, href

I had an *anchor* link that redirects to other page. But i also want to perform click function of C# after redirecting.
My code:

**Home.aspx**

```
<a href='City.aspx' ><span>Test city</span></a>
```

**City.aspx.cs**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" class="linkbtn" runat="server" onclick="ClickEvent1">Test city</asp:LinkButton>
```

On clicking *"Test City"* of **Home.aspx**, i want to redirect to **City.aspx** and also perform *ClickEvent1* automatically from **Home.aspx** without clicking it, after redirection.

Comment: Maybe you can extract the code of your click handler and use it when you reach City.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can find a solution to the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992925/2658953