# Call javascript function from asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two asp.net pages Default.aspx and API.aspx and a javascript file which is linked in the Default.aspx page. It is a single page application. The AJAX call is made from Default.aspx to API page. I want to call the javascript function which is linked in default.aspx from API.aspx code behind. How to call the function.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992828/how-to-call-function-from-one-page-to-another-page-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp

Comment: I want to call the javascript function not the function in the aspx page.